# Revert modified xcdatamodel file to previous version

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode5, core-data-migration

I was not knowing about adding new version before modifying xcdatamodel. So I modified my current xcdatamodel1.5 to add new field. But now I am getting error "can't modify source data model".

And I am also not having old version of project and therefore xcdatamodel file.

I have just added one field.

Can't I recover my old file just by deleting that one field.

Is there any other solution?

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: You want to enable "lightweight migration" in the future, in that it will tolerate simple changes like this... you *don't* have to version the data model numerous times during development.

Comment: Also, even if you don't use version control (and you should) -- Time Machine??  You gotta have backups!

Comment: If you remember what change(s) you made, then yes deleting those will fix your error. Once you ship your product, ALWAYS create a new version of the data model when you make changes.